# Eclipse(Java) anad memory Ram

Tags: java, memory, ram

I have a computer with

```
RAM=16 GB 
Processor= Intel Core i7 ...2.60 Hz
System type = 64-bit Operating ssytem, x64-based processor
```

I am running Java program that handles very large dataset and I want to give the maximum memory.
What do I do?

Comment: You do some research on Java's memory settings.

Comment: Eclipse > Right Click Properties > Give Arguments with -Xms1024m -Xmx4000m in Start in . Should help

Comment: Edit the  '-Xms' '-Xmx' options in `eclipse.ini`